# Send User ID from Windows Phone 8.1 App to Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, mobile, twitter, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 App using C# and XAML where I am authenticating the user via Twitter using Azure Mobile Service.
Now I want to send the User ID of user which Twitter Returns to my App to another Azure Mobile Service which will generate all tweets of that User only.
The Azure mobile Service has backend in JavaScript. Right Now my script generates my tweets because I have hard-coded my Details in it. I want to make it Dynamic so it works on any ID it receives.
How do I send this ID from my App to Azure mobile Service and How do I receive it there and use it in my script?

A video/site tutorial containing solution will be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to get the user ID on the client device or on the backend? Or is this more about how you can move the ID from one Mobile Service backend to another?

Comment: How do I send data from my App to Azure mobile Service and How do I receive it there in Service and use it in my script

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following tutorials helpful:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-call-custom-api/

The ID can simply be sent as the body of a POST request to a table or custom API, and then this would be available to the request object in your scripts.

It is also worth pointing out that the ID of the currently logged-in user is available to any script at `request.user.userId`.